# Persist all the fields properly in the MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, rest, api, spring-boot

I work with a small API where I have all the data before I persist in the database and I can print them accordingly. So, it seems the code works as intended, but, I wasn't able to persist them in the MySQL. The entity classes are provided,

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;


    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "timestamp")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    private java.sql.Timestamp timestamp;

    @Embedded
    private Stock stock;

    public Product() {

    }

    public Product(String id, Timestamp timestamp, Stock stock) {
        this.id = id;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public Stock getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(Stock stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }
}



@Embeddable
public class Stock {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    private java.sql.Timestamp timestamp;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;

    public Stock() {

    }

    public Stock(String id, Timestamp timestamp, int quantity) {

        this.id = id;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

The API is provided below,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/products")
public class ProductAPI {


    @Autowired
    private ProductService service;


    /*
     *
     * $ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{ \"id\": \"Product1 ID\", \"timestamp\": \"2017-07-16 22:54:01.754\", \"stock\" : { \"id\": \"Stock ID\", \"timestamp\": \"3000-07-16 22:54:01.754\", \"quantity\": \"350\" }}" http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/createProduct
     * */
    @PostMapping(value = "/createProduct", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> createProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {


        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Product ID " + product.getId());
        System.out.println("Product timestamp " +product.getTimestamp());

        System.out.println("Stock ID " +product.getStock().getId());
        System.out.println("Stock timestamp " +product.getStock().getTimestamp());
        System.out.println("Stock quantity " +product.getStock().getQuantity());
        System.out.println("\n");

        service.save(product);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(product);
    }
}
```

I made this cURL call for the persisting operation in the database,

```
$ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{ \"id\": \"Product1 ID\", \"timestamp\": \"2017-07-16 22:54:01.754\", \"stock\" : { \"id\": \"Stock ID\", \"timestamp\": \"3000-07-16 22:54:01.754\", \"quantity\": \"350\" }}" http://localhost:8080/api/v1/products/createProduct
```

My print says that all the data came as wished,

```
Product ID Product1 ID
Product timestamp 2017-07-17 00:54:01.754
Stock ID Stock ID
Stock timestamp 3000-07-17 00:54:01.754
Stock quantity 350
```

This is good, but, when I look into the MySQL database, I find that the product timestamp and stock ID are missing.

[image]

For the product timestamp, I need to use the `insertable = false, updatable = false`, otherwise, I get an error. Not sure why the Stock id is not persisting. I can provide the repo and the service code if requested.

How do I persist the data properly in the MySQL?

*UPDATE*

When I removed the @Id annotation form the Stock and renamed it to id1, I am able to persist the value into the database. I am still not able to persist the timestamp for the product into the database.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What I'm missing is, why are you dealing with `Product` and `Stock` in the first place?
`Product` and `Stock` uses the exact same representation, why embed `Stock`?

But anyway. You're *embedding*, which means those columns will be considered part of the same database table.

And you're passing in two different `id`s, `"Product1 ID"` and `"Stock ID"`. You're also mapping the same column `id` to two different fields, `Product#id` and `Stock#id`, which I don't think JPA is supposed to handle.

You're also specifying two times the `@Id` annotation, which won't work.

Comment: The product is more about the company brand and let's take the question as a programming task than delve into the semantic meaning of it. Your answer is helpful - when I removed the `@Id` annotation form the Stock and renamed it to `id1`, I am able to persist the value into the database. 

I am still not able to persist the `timestamp` for the product into the database. Do you have any idea and how to do it?

Comment: @Arefe try moving the insertable and updatable to the Stock#timestamp. And leave the responsibility to insert and update the timestamp to Product.